# How do I serve statical Jira's files with nginx?

Tags: nginx, jira

My actual nginx configuration is like this:

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name jira.domain.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/jira.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/jira.key;
ssl on;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}

}
```

How do I serve statical file with Jira standalone edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx has to be used as a proxy server with Jira standalone edition. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746815/configure-nginx-for-jboss-tomcat). Alternatively you can deploy the Jira jar edition in a container(jboss or tomcat) and couple nginx with it.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to bump the speed up. So I want to serve all I can with nginx avoiding tomcat.